# Does the change in Gibbs free energy depend on initial and final concentrations?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose there is a decomposition reaction, and by varying different factors, the equilibrium can be disturbed to alter the final concentration of compounds. So, does the value of ∆G here depend upon the initial and final concentration? The basic rule of ∆G = G(products) - G(reactants) seems unsatisfactory, because, it seems pretty absurd to me, that the value of ∆G is the same when 0.01% of a gas decomposes, and when 85% of it decomposes.

Comment: You're mistaking molar and total enthalpy

Comment: You may got confused: you assume an equilibrium, yet your intuition seems to be about a non equilibrium decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathrm dG = -S\mathrm dT+ V\mathrm dP + \sum \mu_i \mathrm dN_i$$
If (products) and (reactants) are at the same temperature and pressure then $\mathrm dT$ and $\mathrm dP$ are both $0$, and $\mathrm dG = \sum \mu_i\mathrm dN_i$. Integration gives $\Delta G = \sum \mu_i\Delta N_i$. $\mu$ is the chemical potential which is just the specific molar Gibbs free energy. For the decomposition of $\ce{AB -> B + A}$ this is $$(\mu_\ce{A}\Delta N_\ce{A} + \mu_\ce{B}\Delta N_\ce{B}) - \mu_\ce{AB}\Delta N_\ce{AB}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Please use MathJax for chemical and mathematical expressions; I have edited your post to do so. Check out the [help], [this meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444).

Comment: Where does that formula come from? All I've ever studies is that ∆G = ∆H - T∆S and that ∆G = G(products) - G(reactants)...

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\Delta G = G(products) - G(reactants)$ refers to a change of state in which you start out with pure reactants and end up with pure products.   Of course, if you start out in thermodynamic equilibrium state A (containing an equilibrium mixture of reactants and products) and you make a change so that you end up in thermodynamic equilibrium state B (containing a different equilibrium mixture of reactants and products), the change in free energy is not given by that equation.  However, you should be able to calculate what that change in free energy actually is (between states A and B).

Comment: And, how would that be? Also, if once I completely decompose 1 mol of a substance, and after that 2 mol of it, is the ∆G same? Does the quantity of matter not influence it in any way??

Comment: I can show you how to calculate this, but there would be some "arithmetic" involved.  Are you sure you feel up to it?  Are you familiar with working with  "chemical potentials?"  With regard to your second question, if I understand you correctly, the $\Delta G$ would not be the same.  Since free energy is an extensive property, the quantity of matter does influence it.